# Compilation failed to complete

Tags: android, firebase, compiler-errors, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

https://github.com/Xares01/TimeZoneWorld

It says in the build:

```
Android issues: Program type already 
present: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzo
```

Before I experimented with the build.gradle app file beaucuse it complained about different versions, which I shouldn't had done.

This is my current build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jimjohansson.timezoneworld"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
      implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2"
      implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0',{
          exclude group: 'com.android.support'
      })
      implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
      testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-   core:3.0.1'
      implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
      implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:12.0.1'
      implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: add your error Log

Comment: @NikunjParadva I see a lot of errors in the log. How can I short down it? And its getting more. The time is at 16:24 as highest  I restarted it at 18:05.

Comment: @XaresJ have you tried the answer?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yeah, I tried your answer and it worked. Thanks! unfortunately I can't upvote your comment :/ because I don't have rep 15 yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
```

to this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
```

The firebaseui should be compatible with the firebase version

Refer to this:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies